# Visual Studio C++ linker warning: LNK4006 with C Run-Time (CRT)

Tags: c++, linker-warning

I'm going to ask this question, and then answer it myself. 
I'm, aware that its a newbie question, but as it took me approx. two days to find the correct answer, I'll post it anyway.

So much for disclaimers - this one is dedicated to all you newbies out there:

I've go an MFC project in VS 2010, and I needed to add some 3rd party static library. All went well, both projects compiled and my project managed to reference the library. Then, when I included some header file from the library in my project, I got numerous a linker warnings, about functions in the C Run-Time library, e.g.:

**Warning 9 warning LNK4006: _sprintf already defined in libcmtd.lib(sprintf.obj); second definition ignored C:path\to\my\project\MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)**

Thinking 'what the hell', I tried running my project, and it did run, until it came across a code line which tried to write into some file using 'fostream', and then it crashed with some scary heap corruption exception.

Searching S.O., I came across some related issues, none of which exactly match my problem:

- [Link libraries with dependencies in Visual C++ without getting LNK4006](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564872/link-libraries-with-dependencies-in-visual-c-without-getting-lnk4006)
- [How do you build a debug .exe (MSVCRTD.lib) against a release built lib (MSVCRT.lib)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746298/how-do-you-build-a-debug-exe-msvcrtd-lib-against-a-release-built-lib-msvcrt-l)

I almost wrapped the external library in a dll, before I stumbled across the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My happy ending is that I've stumbled across the correct answer in Microsoft support article: [How to link with the correct C Run-Time (CRT) library](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q140584&) .

Apparently, I violated the following rule, as stated in the articel:

> A reusable library and all of its users should use the same CRT library types and therefore the same compiler switch.

**Meaning that I should have used the same C Run-Time (CRT) library for both project and 3rd party library.** Selecting CRT in VS 2010 can be done by: right-click project_name --> properties (the properties window opens) --> C/C++ --> Code Generation --> Runtime Library. Use the pull-down list and select the runtime library, according to the table in the article (single-threaded, static multi-threaded or dll multi-threaded, release or debug).

After configuring all projects, re-compile them, and (hopefully) the warnings are gone.