# error MSB8024: Using static version of the C++ runtime library is not supported

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I created simple Windows Runtime Component using Visual Studio template. By default project is dynamically linked to C/C++ Runtime Library with MD/MDd option.

When I change it into MT/MTd (Project properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library) and build the project I am getting error

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1693,5): error MSB8024: Using static version of the C++ runtime library is not supported.

How can I compile Windows Runtime Component with MTd option? 
I need this since WinRT Component will refer other 3rd part library which is built with statically linked C++ runtime library.

Comment: The error message is quite explicit, there is no magic button you can push to make it disappear.  Having to rebuild a library to match the compiler version and settings is entirely normal.  If it is not yours then ask the owner for a rebuild.  And keep in mind that such a library is unlikely to work at all in a UWP app, verifying it with WACK is essential.

Comment: The solution is to request a version of the 3rd party library that dynamically links against the same CRT you are using in your component.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't avoid the restriction.

But I have doubts about "I need this since WinRT Component will refer other 3rd part library which is built with statically linked C++ runtime library". Did you try to use that 3rd part library? You should have no problems adding it to your project.

Comment: I can use 3rd party lib only after recompile with MD flag, otherwise I am getting compile error. Btw, do you know if there is a specific reason to add such restriction?

Comment: .NET Framework needs it for some reason. Also look at the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564872/link-libraries-with-dependencies-in-visual-c-without-getting-lnk4006

Comment: @miradham: Statically linking against the CRT imposes undue restrictions. See [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries) for details, why you always want to dynamically link against the CRT. And always link against the same CRT.

Comment: or just don't pass CRT objects across DLL boundaries ;)

Comment: This isn't something you have any control over. It's the 3rd party library that made the decision already. You cannot change that after the fact.

Comment: Yes, but most libraries use C-style interfaces for the reason